# Returning an Item Back Into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Attempting to solve the cabbage, wolf, and goat problem. My game plan is to create two arrays, one representing the left side of the river bank and the other representing the right side. Basically, if two items in an array threaten each other, for example, if the left side array contains the goat and the cabbage, it will not allow one to move the wolf out. I have my arrays set up, but when I call the function to return the item (cabbage, wolf, goat) it does not place it back into the leftSide array. I am using splice() to add the item back in. Is that the problem? Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
function returnCabbage(){
    $("#cabbage2").hide();
    $("#cabbage").show();
    leftBank.splice(0, 1, cabbage.name);
    rightBank.splice(0, 1);

    console.log(leftBank.length);

    console.log(cabbage.name + " on left bank: " +   isOnLeftBank(cabbage.name));
    console.log(cabbage.name + " on right bank: " + isOnRightBank(cabbage.name));
}

function sendCabbage(){
    $("#cabbage2").show();
    $("#cabbage").hide();
    leftBank.splice(0, 1);
    rightBank.splice(0, 1, cabbage.name);

    console.log(rightBank.length);

    console.log(cabbage.name + " on left bank: " + isOnLeftBank(cabbage.name));
    console.log(cabbage.name + " on right bank: " + isOnRightBank(cabbage.name));
}
```

There are more details here: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/m7vb3eoj/6/ (images won't load and the format of the page is way off).

Comment: jsfiddle does not contain the html. please update it

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: your jsfiddle is broken. All of your functions (sendWolf, etc) need to be on the window (jsfiddle auto wraps ur stuff in a IFFE). You need `window.sendWolf` to make the fiddle work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you splice to place you are replacing an element in the array.  When you splice to remove you are reducing the length of the array.  Instead you can use push to push onto the array.  The problem is your code assumes a specific position for each element.  I would recommend a slightly different method.  Below is more what I would recommend.  I left the checking for failure state and such to you.

```js
/* true for left false for right */
var river = {
  cabbage: true,
  wolf: true,
  goat: true
}

function sendItem(name) {
  river[name] = !river[name];
  setState();
};

function setState() {
  Object.keys(river).forEach(function(k) {
    if (river[k] === true) {
      $('.left .' + k).show();
      $('.right .' + k).hide();
    } else {
      $('.left .' + k).hide();
      $('.right .' + k).show();
    }
  });
}

setState();
```

```css
.river,
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left,
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="river">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="cabbage">Cabbage</div>
    <div class="wolf">Wolf</div>
    <div class="goat">Goat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="cabbage">Cabbage</div>
    <div class="wolf">Wolf</div>
    <div class="goat">Goat</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" onclick="sendItem('cabbage')">Send Cabbage</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendItem('wolf')">Send Wolf</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendItem('goat')">Send Goat</button>
</div>
```